# jQuery getJson in a loop stops looping after n number of loops

Tags: javascript, jquery, getjson, each

Hi I have currency pair exchange rates displayed on top of a page. The rate values are pulled in with getJson in a loop for each pair. On my dev server al is good, but on live server the loop stops execution after 4th sometimes 5th iteration with no errors in console.

```
var tapeQuotePairs = [
  "EUR/USD",
  "GBP/USD",
  "AUD/USD",
  "USD/CAD",
  "USD/JPY",
  "USD/CHF",
  "USD/ZAR",
  "XAU/USD",
  "USD/BRL",
  "BTC/USD"
];

$.each(tapeQuotePairs, function(i, item) {

  var bc = item.split("/"); 

  $.getJSON(quoteUrl, {
      base: bc[0],
      quote: bc[1]
  })
  .done(function(data) {
    console.log(qi);
    console.log(quoteUrl); 
    qi++;
    if (qi == qCsize) {
      qSeparator = "";
    }else{
      qSeparator = ":::";
    }
    $("#ticktape").append(bc[0] + bc[1] + data.rate.toFixed(4) + qSeparator);
    })
  .fail(function() { 
    $("#ticktape").append(bc[0] + bc[1] + "n/a");
  });

});
```

Comment: whether all the requests are sent?

Comment: Does the `fail` function ever get executed?

Comment: Where is `qi` coming from ?

Comment: It's quite possibly something to do with the many ajax requests being triggered simultaneously.  Perhaps your server is getting overloaded?

Comment: @jwatts1980 No `fail` never executes. It just stops after about 4 or so loops with no errors.

Comment: @adeneo Sorry `qi` is just a counter initialized to 0 higher up in the script used to not print the last separator.

Comment: @RobSchmuecker You may be right, Rob. Although it's really not a lot of data.

Comment: @ArunPJohny Not sure what you mean. All the requests are not executing. The counter comes to about 4 or 5 and then just stops.

Answer (score 1):

I looked at the error log of my live server and found this:

> [Thu Aug 29 23:44:00 2013] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] (12)Cannot
>   allocate memory: couldn't create child process: /somedirectory/suphp/sbin/suphp
>   for /some/home/public_html/xxx.php, referer:
>   http://example.com/

I added a 1 second delay before every request and also changed `memory_limit = 16M;` to `memory_limit = 256M;` in php.ini. (shared hosting)

No problems so far. (Thanks @RobSchmuecker for pointing me in the right direction)